# Temporary price drop when item added to cart

Tags: cart, addtocart

Was at Amazon today and noticed when I added an item to my cart, it immediately took like 10% off of my order total but said the 10% offer was only good for so many minutes and then the offer would end. Does anybody know of a Magento module that does this? Would be nice to also run it after hours to encourage more sales.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking at [Cart Price Rule](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html). According to official document:

> Cart price rules apply discounts to items in the shopping cart, based on a set of conditions

This rule will only show on the cart page, and you can set start date and end date on the rule.

Comment: That won't allow restricting the offer to minutes - the smallest time would be 24 hours

Comment: Yes it's a limitation. If you need it in minute, you need a 3rd party module.